# Height of View in react native

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

Is it possible to make the `<View />` having the same height? I am fetching a data from server side and some content are short and some are long. So when I display them in a box form, the height of the box aren't same. If I fix the height or minimum height the long text will exceed the height of the box.

**EDIT : Sample code**

```
DisplayEguides(){
  var winsWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;

  if(this.state.eguides != null){
    var eguides = this.state.eguides.map((data, i)=>(
      <View key={i} style={[ { width: (60/100)*winsWidth, paddingHorizontal: 5 } ]}>
        <TouchableOpacity 
          onPress={()=>this.OpenUrl(data.url)}
          style={{ backgroundColor: '#ffffff', borderBottomWidth: 1, borderColor: '#efefef', elevation: 1, shadowOpacity: 0.8, marginBottom: 15, padding: 15, borderRadius: 15 }}>
          <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', overflow: 'hidden', position: 'relative' }}>
            <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', textAlign: 'center', marginBottom: 15 }}>{ data.title }</Text>
            <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
              <Text style={{ color: Color.default, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>Download</Text>
              <AntDesign name="download" size={16} color={Color.default} style={{ paddingLeft: 10, fontWeight: 'bold' }} />
            </View>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    ))

    return (
      <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 15 }}>
        <AppText type="bold" style={{ fontSize: 18, marginBottom: 15 }}>E-Guides</AppText>
        <ScrollView horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>{ eguides }</ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share some more info. like your js code?

Comment: if you have only 1 view just dont give any height, it will automatically consume the required height

Comment: @M.HassamYahya I have multiple view that I get from dynamic data stored in an array. I use mapping to loop all the data and the output will display multiple view. Each of the view has a different height based on the length of the content received from server side.

Comment: And if you notice from my code, I use `<ScrollView></ScrollView>` to display them horizontally, hence I have to make sure their height are same.

Comment: you can set number of lines for that text let say 2 if the content has more than 2 lines ... will be added at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like Flexbox in react native is doing the job but need to place at the right element. Setting the view to `flex: 1` will auto adjust all content inside it to have the same height. In my case, I have to set `flex: 1` at `TouchableOpacity` since my box style is in this element.

```
<TouchableOpacity 
onPress={()=>this.OpenUrl(data.url)}
style={{ backgroundColor: '#ffffff', borderBottomWidth: 1, borderColor: '#efefef', elevation: 1, shadowOpacity: 0.8, marginBottom: 15, padding: 15, borderRadius: 15, flex: 1 }}>
  { /* The rest of code goes here */ }
</TouchableOpacity>
```